# angularjs directive template with ng-bind-html in it, that uses scope of directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-bind-html

i have a directive, whose template is just `<div ng-bind-html="myhtml"></div>`.
But the `myhtml` uses the scope of the directive.

I can´t get this work.

Example: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gWjY/446/)

Comment: What is the expected result? `<div>Hallo Welt</div>` ?

Answer (score 1):

Basically this is not what bind-html is for, when you are looking to dynamically add html to your app, you need to check out [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24compile). This in combination with the typo that others have pointed out. I created a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TVh87/) that shows your solution:

```
link: function(scope, elt, attrs) {
    var element = angular.element(scope.myhtml);
    var test = $compile(element)(scope);
    elt.append(test);
}
```

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

As you don't reference an expected result, I assume you want your directive to display *at least something* from the Controller's scope.

Mainly, you've defined your directive like this:

```
.directive('testDirective',
```

This is fine, however you're referencing it as follows:

```
<testDirective myvar="myvar" myhtml="myhtml" />
```

[This is *not* OK](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_matching-directives) - you should reference your directive with `test-directive` and not `testDirective`, [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/5gWjY/448/):

```
<test-directive myvar="myvar" myhtml="myhtml" />
```